# Need Clarification - Python For loops using a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

```
def check(temp):
  for i in temp:
    if type(i) == str:
      temp.remove(i)

temp = ['a', 'b']
print(temp)    ==> Output: ['a','b']
check(temp)
print(temp)    ==> Output: ['b']
```

When run with

temp = [ 'a', 1 ], Output is [1]

temp = [ 1, 'a', 'b', 'c', 2 ], Output is [ 1, 'b', 2 ]

Could someone care to explain how the result is evaluated.. Thnx

Answer (score 5):

You are modifying the list while iterating it. It will skip elements because the list changes during the iteration. Removing items with `list.remove()` will also remove the first occurence of that element, so there might be some unexpected results.

The canonical way of removing elements from a list is to construct a *new* list, like so:

```
>>> def check(temp):
...    return list(x for x in temp if not isinstance(x, str))
```

Or you could return a regular list comprehension:

```
>>> def check(temp):
...     return [x for x in temp if not isinstance(x, str)]
```

You should generally test for types with [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#isinstance) instead of `type()`. `type` has no idea about inheritance for example.

Examples:

```
>>> check(['a', 'b', 1])
[1]

>>> check([ 1, 'a', 'b', 'c', 2 ])
[1, 2]

>>> check(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
[]
```

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary No reason, might as well use a list comprehension, I guess I've just recently written a lot of generator expressions.

Comment: @eryksun a naive ipython `%timeit` test for both functions with a list of ~200k elements shows a difference of ~3-5 ns. Sure it's slower but half the time seems like an exaggeration, unless I'm timing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ,

```
def check(temp):
    return [i for i in temp if type(i)!=str]

temp = [ 1, 'a', 'b', 'c', 2 ]

print check(temp)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2]
```

***OR***

```
def check(temp):
    return [i for i in temp if not isinstance(i, str)]

temp = [ 1, 'a', 'b', 'c', 2 ,"e",4,5,6,7]

print check(temp)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> text = ['a', 'b', 1, {}]
>>> filter(lambda x: type(x) == str, text)
['a', 'b']
```

function will be like:

```
>>> def check(temp):
...     return list(filter(lambda x: type(x) == str, temp))
... 
>>> check(text)
['a', 'b']
```